# missing a using directive or an assembly reference OperationContext

Tags: c#, directive

In My c# windows form it has a error

> The type or namespace name 'OperationContext' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

can any one explain me the reason??

Answer (score 1):

[OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) is a class defined in the assembly `System.ServiceModel` contained in the library file `System.ServiceModel.dll`

If you try to use this class you need to add the reference to the library through [Project References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then add a

```
using System.ServiceModel;
```

in the file using OperationContext

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't add the dll for access this class

read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx

you have to add System.ServiceModel dll

Comment: Thank you My Friends It's Working and good for my Knowledge :-)